# C++ Implementing a tree containing multiple types with templates

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, tree

I am trying to implement a complex structure for a project of mine, but I don't know how to proceed.

The structure itself is a tree, where every node has a string id and is either a tree or a container for one of the supported data types, somewhat like json data.

```
tree: {
    value1: 4,
    value2: {
        value3: 40.2f,
    }
}
```

Now I managed to have something working in C, but I would like to learn more about C++ and templates, so I am trying my hand at doing something cleaner here. I could use the very powerful [nlohmann json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) and hope to achieve something similar yet I would not have learned anything.

My big question is how to handle the fact that the endpoints have multiple types. I had this in mind going into the project:

```
template<class T>
class basic_node {
    private:
        std::string id;
        std::map<const std::string&, T> contents;
};
```

But the definition of a tree would pose several issue, `T` being as repetitive as the tree's height, and only capable of holding one single data type.

Now digging in code, I found this:

```
template<template<typename U, typename V, typename... Args> class ObjectType =
         std::map,
         template<typename U, typename... Args> class ArrayType = std::vector,
         class StringType = std::string, class BooleanType = bool,
         class NumberIntegerType = std::int64_t,
         class NumberUnsignedType = std::uint64_t,
         class NumberFloatType = double,
         template<typename U> class AllocatorType = std::allocator,
         template<typename T, typename SFINAE = void> class JSONSerializer =
         adl_serializer>
class basic_json;
```

Do I need something like this to allow multitype trees ?

Comment: If you know up front what types you are going to support, then check out `std::variant`.

Comment: or `std::any` if you don't

Comment: There's of course a slight implementation challenge with a node that contains itself. Your variant may need to include `std::unique_ptr<basic_node>` instead of `basic_node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for a while, and found a solution. I wanted to avoid `C` as much as I could but in the end, what is `C++` but `C` with a bunch of stuff ?

The comments are correct, using `std::variant` or an union are the way to go, and do not be afraid of using pointers towards next nodes.

There is also a bunch of stuff doable with the types of values for switch-cases and return values.